# How many user defined schemas we can have in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to know how many user defined schemas we can create in SQL Server. Please tell me..

Like maximum number of user defined schema we can create in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Schemas are just objects in the databases so they are all comes under the maximum objects counters which has the limit of **2,147,483,647.**

Feel free to drop a message if you need more info.

Comment: @Megharaj, that is true. Hope you have got the answer for the question.

Comment: @MegharajShetty: if you create 2,147,483,647 schemas in your SQL Server, then you *cannot* create anything else - no table, no view, nothing.